# Ubuntu 13.04 Dual boot UEFI Windows 8 Preinstalled ACER

Tags: dual-boot, windows-8, uefi, 13.04

I have read so many tutorials here on other places, but never see an instruction that is suitable for me.
I have tried to boot secureboot in UEFI boot all seems fine in the installation, but after the installatiuon that seems to work good as dual boot, I just get windows 8 at the boot loader lines, which looks like Grub , but I am not sure really. But no sign of the Ubuntu instalation just the windows 8 option.
So my question is if there is a complete tutorial. Or do I have to wait until 13.04 is finally released?
Yes there is tutorials like " http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2012/11/05/dual-boot-windows-8-and-ubuntu-12-10-on-uefi-hardware/ " but it does not work at all they use both a lot of partitions but not clearly say explain the efi boot wich imply they did not use this method at all., not clearly say if this is a secure boot or something different and use easybcd windows program.

Answer (score -1):

I found this link that might be helpful, especially the last bit about the bootloader:

http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2012/11/05/dual-boot-windows-8-and-ubuntu-12-10-on-uefi-hardware/

Jack

Comment: How du I make this not a duplicate, the problem is completely different? 1. When you try install by UEFi 64 bit Ubuntu you never see the windows partition. That is the first problem.

Comment: Link has nothing to do with UEFI booting - cheap EasyBCD spamming ! The tutorial is for BIOS booting. (-1)

Comment: Yes that was what I discovered, I I asssume there is no tutorial you can follow to dual-boot Ubuntu 13.04 and windows8 64 bit uefi installation??

Comment: I finally solved the problem))))

Comment: I finally solved the problem)))) The problem was to disable secure boot and still have UEFI enabled. I did not  seem to find any solution to seperate theese two things. But I read something interesting  about ACER boot menues  and they said you need to set a password in bios menu to be able to disable the Secure boot. So I tried that. And I was suddenly able to disable the secure boot. I restarted the computer, and ran BOOT-repair and followed all instructions given by Boot-repair. Then restarted and finally the Windows 8 was bootable just as Ubuntu 13.04