# question about dual boot surface pro with ubuntu

Tags: 13.04, dual-boot, grub2, windows-8, surface

I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong, after I install ubuntu using a usb as suggested through [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/265644/dual-boot-surface-pro-with-ubuntu) post, the installation seems to be okay, but when i reboot, it just boot right back into windows... am i suppose to install the bootloader in a specific place in order for it to boot into it? am I suppose to somehow install grub first into somewhere so that when surface starts it will know to boot into the grub first?  Please help :)

Comment: just noticed another post, gonna give [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/276793/ubuntu-13-04-dual-boot-uefi-windows-8-preinstalled-acer?rq=1) a try

Comment: I've tried to use easyBCD etc and tried installing with a /boot partition etc, none of which seems to work.  The easyBCD lets me add an entry but it always fail to load (saying \NST\AutoNeoGrub0.mbr not found or corrupted...)

Comment: found something else, will follow [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI) for another try...

Comment: yep, the last bit helped, so after installing everything, the tablet still boots into windows.  I had to boot into the installer usb then fiddle around with the wifi until it connects and actually have a connection, then install grub-repair stated in your guide, which then seems to load the grub as the boot loader instead of the windows one.  I tried to follow the rest of your guide with the nice looking boot screen but alas I have the same problem with the theme and windows won't boot so I had to disable that too and use the default grub loader, but everything is booting fine now!

Comment: hone question for you though Brandon, did you see 3 wifi device appearing on your ubuntu install as well? I dunno why but i see 3 marvell devices and each time i try to set up wifi all 3 of them tries to connect and eventually fails... I had to manually disconnect 2 of them and hope the 3rd one actually connects everytime... this is for 13.04... maybe I have to wait for a newer release to have that fixed :P

Comment: I have 13.04 installed which i believe uses kernel 3.8.8 but so far I have no problem on booting up, although I've seen it giving some error before but eventually it booted into the desktop either way.  I haven't tried 13.10 yet but will probably give that a try once I have some time to test it.